Is there any sdk for .net core for create standard front door?
Is there any sdk for .net core for create standard front door?
I'm currently working on a project using .NET Core, and I need to create an Azure Front Door Standard instance programmatically. I've explored various Azure SDKs, but I'm unsure which one to use for this specific task. Or is there any way to achieve it?

No, I believe there is no such SDK to do it programmatically. Also there is no CLI for this. You have to configure it from UI.

@Md.KhirulIslamOmi there absolutely is a CLI for it.

@PeterBons I think the question is edited after I answer it. I can recall the version based on which I answered, were asking for different context. However, lets move on!

Yes there is. Azure Resources are created using the Azure Resource Manager:

Azure Resource Manager is the deployment and management service for Azure. It provides a management layer that enables you to create, update, and delete resources in your Azure account.

The Azure Resource Manager can be invoked using

PowerShell
ARM / Bicep templates (docs)
Azure Cli (see the docs)
Rest Api
Various language specific Azure Resource Manager SDKs

See the docs for getting started managing Azure Front Door resources using the  Azure .NET SDK Management Libraries.
There are no specific examples on how to create a Front Door resources but all resources follow the same concepts so you should be able to figure out how to apply the other examples to your use case.
